# How to use counters in functions

Tags: c++

I am trying to get a program to print out a star based on which number was entered by the used, e.g a number between 10-20 = 1 etc.  My problem is I do not know how to get the print to function to work as at the moment it does not print anything out. Can anyone help.

Code:

```
void readExamMarks(int examMarks[], int sizeOfArray, int counter1, int counter2){

cout << "Please enter a set of exam marks to see a histogram for:" << endl;
int x = 0;

for( int idx = 0; idx < sizeOfArray; idx++){
    cin >> x;
     if((x >=0) && (x <= 100)){
            x = x/10;

            switch(x){
            case 1:
                counter1++;

                break;
            case 2:
                counter2++;
                break;

            }

            examMarks[idx] = x;
        }
             else{
             cout << "ERROR: Value must be in range [0...100], please    enter a valid value\n"; 
         }
}
}


void printExamMarks(int examMarks[], int sizeOfArray){

for(int x = 0; x < sizeOfArray; x++){

    cout << setw(5) << examMarks[x];
}
cout << endl;
}

void printHisto(int examMarks[], int sizeOfArray,int counter1, int counter2){
system("cls");

while(counter1 != 0){
    cout << "*" << endl;
    counter1--;
}
for( int x = 0; x < counter1; x++){
cout << setw(5) << "*" << endl;
}
 }

int main() 
{ 
int examMarks[20];
int counter1 = 0;
int counter2 = 0;

readExamMarks(examMarks, 5, counter1, counter2);
printHisto(examMarks, 5, counter1, counter2);
printExamMarks(examMarks,5);


system("PAUSE");
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is a bit strange, and I'm having some trouble following it. But I think the mistake you are making it that you are assuming that because you increment the variables `counter1` and `counter2` in `readExamMarks` then is somehow going to affect the values of `counter1` and `counter2` in `printHisto`. That's not true. You change the value in `readExamMarks` but that has no effect on the vairable in `main`, and so when you call `printHisto` `counter1` and `counter2` are still zero.

What you should understand is that variables in different functions are different variables even if they have the same name. If you want `readExamMarks` to change the variables in `main` then you should use references.

```
void readExamMarks(int examMarks[], int sizeOfArray, int& counter1, int& counter2)
{
    ...
}
```

By using `int&` instead of `int` `counter1` and `counter2` are now *references* to the variables in `main`, not *copies* of the variables in main.

Comment: I have been learning for about a week, so I don't really know about coding proper, If this is not the case then is it possible to pass the counter1 and counter2 as a param into printHisto from readExamMarks?

Comment: @Thomas, No simply because readExamMarks does not call printHisto. Both are called from main. You need to use references to achieve what you want, as I explain above.

Answer (score 0):

```
printHisto(examMarks, 5, counter1, counter2);
```

will not print anything reason is counter1  and counter2 are initialize with 0, and they are passed as it is to the printHisto(...), my guess is you intend readExamMarks(...) to modify your counter(1,2), if that is the case, pass them by ref http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/functions2/